# Is a set created by induction necessarily an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I know that just because a proposition is true on an arbitrary finite set does not mean it is true for an infinite set, the obvious counterexample being $P(S)$ where $P$ is "$S $ is a finite set".

But say I have $P(x)$, and have proven $P(0)$, and $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$. By induction, $P$ is true for the set of natural numbers. Can I say the set $S=\{x:P(x)\}$ is an infinite set? I feel like intuitively this should be true, but I know infinity isn't always intuitive and I also had somebody tell me this was not true.

Comment: Well, you *HAVE* proven that $P(x)$ is true of $x \in \mathbb N$ so you *HAVE* proven that $\mathbb N \subset S$.  Does that mean $S$ is infinite?

Comment: ... but the question I guess I really have is "a set created by".  Created by how, exactly.  I've exhausted the set set $\{x: P(x)$ is true$\}$ but is it possible for induction to "create" another set.  Suppose we have $S_0 = \emptyset$ and $S_{k} = S_{k-1} \cup \{x\in \mathbb Z_7| x\equiv k\}$ the $S = \cup S_k$ would have $S$ finite as it'd be $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}=\mathbb Z_7$.  It was "created" by induction but not in the way you set up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S = \{x: P(x)\}$ is all we know we have no idea if $S$ is finite or infinite.  For all we know $S$ could be empty and it never true.

Now, if $P(0)$ is true then we know $0\in S$ and $S$ is not empty, but it could be finite.

But if $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ then by induction we know that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  So we *know* that $n \in S$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

That statement is nothing more or less than $\mathbb N \subset S$.

Now, I don't know if and how you have proven $\mathbb N$ is infinite, or if you have proven that any set with an infinite subset must be infinite.... But I'll assume that it is intuitive that that means $S$ has to be infinite.

So yes:  If $P(0)$ is true and $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ then YES  $P(n); n\in \mathbb N$ and so $\mathbb N \subset S= \{x:P(x)\}$ and so YES $S$ is infinite.

.......

!!BUT!!

......

Now there are plenty of statements $Q(x)$ where $T = \{x:Q(x)\}$ are finite.  For example if $Q(x) = $ "$x$ is a natural number so that $x^2 < 10$ then $T = \{x:Q(x)\} = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $T$ is finite.

But you obviously *cant* do induction on such a $Q$ (I challenge *anyone* to try to prove that if $k \in \mathbb N$ and $k^2 < 10$ then that means $(k+1)^2 < 10$.  It can't be proven because it is *not* true:  $3\in \mathbb N$ and $3^2 < 10$ but $(3+1)^2 \ge 10$.).

And as we have shown every statement that is provable by induction must yield an infinite set.  Then any statement that *doesn't* yield an infinite set, can not have the induction property.

But that's okay as statements don't need to have the induction property.  Indeed, most statements don't.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(0)$ is true, and if $\forall n (P(n) \implies P(n+1))$ is true, then $\mathbb{N} \subset \{x : P(x)\}$. This is the law of induction. In particular, this implies that $\{x : P(x)\}$ must be infinite, at least countable.